# If Account is deleted from web panel,then user should get auto logout from the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to do something like as below in swift

If Account is deleted from web panel,then user should get auto logout from the app.

can you guys give me some idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two ways to achieve this.

1. Maintain a flag in every API about the account delete. Enable the flag on account delete action. After getting the response from the API check the flag and let the app to logout.
2. We can send silent PUSH notification from the server. When ever we trigger delete account then send a PUSH. And you will let the app to logout.